# three tables with Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three tables...

```
Table1
IDA    colB    colC    
111       a       w    
222       b       w    
333       c       s        
444       b       g    



Table2
IDB    colB    colC    
11       w       f    
12      w       r    
13      s       g    



Table3
IDA     IDB       
111     11         
222     12           
333     13       
444     14
```

What I need is to copy from table1 to table2 and I could use the following easy MySQL query to do that...

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1
```

The problem is I don't the same id type,...the two tables are connected over the third table table3.
in which IDA contains table1 primary key and IDB contain table2 primary key,

so, example if I want to copy from table1 IDA(111) to table2 how do I do that?
and if the IDB exists how do I update on Duplicate Key...

I have the following query but no working...

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE IDA IN ( SELECT table1 b 
INNER JOIN table3 c ON c.IDA = b.IDA 
INNER JOIN table2 a ON a.IDB = c.IDB ) 
WHERE b.IDA=111
```

But, I wish if I get generalize answer...Thanks

Comment: see this post this will help you http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10472/join-three-tables

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT 
    t3.idb
    ,t1.colb as ncolb
    ,t1.colc as ncolc
FROM 
    table1 t1
    join table3 t3
    on t1.ida = t3.ida
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    colb = ncolb
    ,colc = ncolc
```

No MySQL on me right now so syntax might not be 100% correct, but this should give you the idea of how it should be done.
Depending on whether `table3` has entry for each `table1 id` you might need to change `t3.idb` to `coalesce(t3.idb, t1.ida)` and change `join` to `left join` in the query if you want them to be copied. Remember that `table2` will then have ids from table1)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE IDA IN ( SELECT * FROM table1 b 
INNER JOIN table3 c ON c.IDA = b.IDA 
INNER JOIN table2 a ON a.IDB = c.IDB ) HAVING b.IDA=111
```